# passing datagridview data to another datagridview 'System.NullReferenceException'

Tags: vb.net

I need help for this problem and i have no idea on how to solve this.

This is the code;

```
Private Sub GetLabandOtherFees()
        Dim dic As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()
        Dim cellValue As String = Nothing
        For i As Integer = 0 To dgvSubjectsEnrolled.Rows.Count - 1
            If Not dgvSubjectsEnrolled.Rows(i).IsNewRow Then
                cellValue = dgvSubjectsEnrolled(0, i).Value.ToString()
                If Not dic.ContainsKey(cellValue) Then
                    dic.Add(cellValue, 1)
                Else
                    dic(cellValue) += 1
                End If
            End If
        Next

        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
        For Each keyvalue As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer) In dic
            sb.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}", keyvalue.Key, keyvalue.Value))
        Next

        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvsub.Rows
            row.Cells(0).Value = sb.ToString()
            row.Cells(1).Value = dic.Count.ToString()
        Next
    End Sub
```

And this is the error;

```
"Object Reference Not set to an instance of an object." 
Check to determine if object is null before calling the method.
```

This error is putting headache on me. please help.

Comment: Where in this code does the error occur and what does the look like?

Comment: This part.    "cellValue = dgvSubjectsEnrolled(0, i).Value.ToString()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read what was in the error. Here it is, try this one, just add a little bit of conditions in it.

```
               If dgvSubjectsEnrolled(0, i).Value > 0 Then
                    cellValue = dgvSubjectsEnrolled(0, i).Value.ToString()
                    If Not dic.ContainsKey(cellValue) Then
                        dic.Add(cellValue, 1)
                    Else
                        dic(cellValue) += 1
                    End If
                Else
                End If
```

Comment: yeah! thanks a lot. great job..